# How to visualize the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^\times / \langle 1 + \sqrt{2} \rangle $

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to count the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ modulo its units, so I'll remove the set $\{ 0\}$ but also the group of units $\{ (1 + \sqrt{2})^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  So this would be the quotient set $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^\times /  (1 + \sqrt{2})^\mathbb{Z} $.

So I am going to place my copy of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ in the plane using:

$$ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] = \{ (a,b\sqrt{2}): a,b \in \mathbb{Z}  \}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $$

One possible lattice point counting problem could be a circle or an ellipse, we could count elements of the set:

$$ \{ x^2 + y^2 < R^2\} \cap  \{ (a,b\sqrt{2}): a,b \in \mathbb{Z}  \} $$

This does not seem natural since the norm for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has to do with [hyperbolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola):

$$ N(a + b \sqrt{2}) = a^2 - 2b^2 = n $$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ranges over the integers.  This is a family of hyperbolas, preserved under the action of $ \times \,(\,1 + \sqrt{2})$.

---

In that case, what are the [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) sets of $\mathbb{C}^\times $ modulo the action of $ \times \,(\,1 + \sqrt{2})$ ?

I have drawn the folation and transverse foliations of the hyperbola, which cover the pictured Euclidean plane:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 - 2y^2&=& a \\
\sqrt{2} \, xy&=& b 
\end{eqnarray*}

[image]

Here the element $1 + \sqrt{2}$ acts as:

$$ (1 + \sqrt{2}) (a + b \sqrt{2}) = (a + 2b) + \sqrt{2}(a+b) $$

and this can be modeled as a $2 \times 2$ matrix

$$ 1 + \sqrt{2} \leftrightarrow 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}  \right] $$

---

**Back to the original problem** I'd liked to list elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ that are "smaller than" say 100 up to the action of the unit $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$.  This has motivated me to define some peculiar sets of the plane, but I still cannot get an answer.

Hopefully I have explained what I am looking for.

Comment: There are units that aren’t of that form. You need to add $\pm$ to the expression.

Comment: Also, be careful. $R^{\times}$ often actually means the group of units, not the non-zero elements of $R.$

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, but it is too long for the comment box.

The embedding $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that you picked is not the most convenient one for studying this type of problem, as your comment about norms suggests.

There is a much better embedding, namely 
$$a + b \sqrt{2} \mapsto (a + b \sqrt{2},a - b \sqrt{2})
$$ 
This embedding has many advantages in connection with your problem: like the embedding you chose, its image is discrete: the norm is given by the simple formula $|(x,y)| = xy$; both the addition and the multiplication are operators given by coordinate-wise operation on vectors; multiplication by any particular unit is given by a simple diagonal matrix in $(x,y)$ coordinates.

This is discussed in many elementary number theory books -- there is a similar discrete embedding for the ring of integers of any number field. I suspect your counting problem will be simplified by using this point of view.

Comment: I'm just trying to count lattice points

Comment: Yes. And as I said, it may possibly be easier to count with a better geometric model than the one you chose. Or maybe not.